# show different item on selectionchange on a grid

Tags: grid, extjs4, selectionchanged

i have a grid and a form, i need to  show different items on the form each time we select a row on that grid

i ve been looking on how to do this, and found

```
    Ext.getCmp('myform').hide() // or  .show()
```

and

```
    listeners: { selectionchange: function () {...}
```

now i dont know which row is selected so i can specify which item to show

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to following code in your grid.

```
        listeners:{
                itemclick:function(view, record, item, index, e ) {
                var v = record.get('firstName');
                ....
                    ....
                     }
                  }
```

**firstName** will be your dataindex of colums in your grid.
You can get value of any field like this.

Answer (score 6):

You get the selected rows as second parameter in the `selectionchange` event handler:

```
listeners: {
    selectionchange: function (view, selections, options) {
        console.log(view, selections, options);
    }
}
```

So the first selected row is the first element in the `selections` array:

```
record = selections[0]
```

This is described in the Ext JS 4 API documentation for the [selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange) event.